# Should HTML div elements be buttons if I am creating a to-do list?

Tags: javascript, html, github, web

So, I want to create a to-do list, but currently, I don't know if I should make my HTML elements be a button to be clickable or leave them as they are and add JavaScript that can transform my divs into a clickable to-do list. Currently, all I have is my HTML, I have not yet touched JS nor CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-Do-List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="side-bar">
           <div class="profile">profile</div>
              <ul class="side-items">
                 <li class="home">Home</li>
                 <li class="tasks">Tasks</li>
                 <li class="calender">Calender</li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is up to you, but from the description of what you want to do, I would not use buttons.

Comment: Your provided HTML doesn't really look like a todo list. However, if you are asking if your add, update, delete actions should be buttons, then I would say yes.  You can turn a div into clickable, but to make it make sense to the user you would also have to change the cursor in the CSS and more nonsense, just to duplicate the look and feel of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far you have done everything through HTML directly, so I would recommend that you add a '`onclick`' on each element.

**BUT** if you planned to expand the project and make js that creates the HTML then I would recommend you do it through js.

I think it's not too difficult to transform it later down the road.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Please recommend the usage of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener) over [inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) like `onclick`.